# How to use a third party dll, header, and lib file with Node N-API

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I have been given all of the appropriate files to use a c++ dll:

- header file
- lib file
- dll

I am attempting to use [Node N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_functions_to_convert_from_c_types_to_n_api) with the given files so we can use this c++ dll in our node server.

The problem is that when I try to build with node-gyp it throws the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'lib\MathUtils.lib' [C:\Development\Github\node-thin-client\service\build\interface.vcxproj]
```

The node version I am using is: 8.11.2

The node-gyp version is: 3.6.2

my binding.gyp file is as follows:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "dll_files": [
      "lib/MathUtils.dll"
    ]
  },
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "interface",
      "sources": [
        "src/interface/interface.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
        "include"
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "lib/MathUtils.lib"
      ],
      "cflags!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "cflags_cc!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "defines": ["NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into similar problems.  I see it's been a while but in case anyone else runs into this while building a node plugin that links to other dlls, here is what I did:

You are getting the link error because the project file is generated in the `./build` directory under your project, but you referenced the `./lib/MathUtils.lib`.  If you opened the generated .sln project in Visual Studio you would see the problem.  So you can do:

```
"libraries": [../lib/MathUtils.lib"]
```

or

```
"libraries": [ "<(module_root_dir)/lib/MathUtils.lib" ]
```

Note, first the relative path goes up one directory.  The second one will put the full path in the linker line of the project.

Also for me the `variables` section did not copy the dll to the release directory, it seemed to do nothing.  Instead I used a copies section:

```
     "conditions": [        
        ["OS==\"win\"", {
          "libraries": [ "<(module_root_dir)/tsflexnet/TSFlexnetCLib.lib" ],
          "copies": [
            {
              "destination": "<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/",
              "files": [ "<(module_root_dir)/tsflexnet/TSFlexnetCLib.dll" ]
            }
          ]
        }]
      ]
```